# Getting code":"900901","message":"Invalid Credentials","description":"Invalid Credentials

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Have an portal that works on infrasture with nginx, wso2 and nodejs server. While testing the portal or while performing load testing, im randomly receiving
code":"900901","message":"Invalid Credentials","description":"Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
Post after multiple refreshes on the portal, im receiving correct response and able to login to the portal and in case of load testing out of 10, 3 -4 responses will be with the above error.
Kindly advice what could be the issue and how can this be resolved

Comment: Could you please explain more about the setup ? How the WSO2 involve in this setup ? Portal means WSO2 API Manager dev/publisher portal or something you have designed using set of APIs ? Do you get this error when invoking managed APIs in API Manager ?